# \includegraphics: number sign # in filename

Tags: graphics

I have hundreds of figures with filenames containing "#" to include using `\includegraphics`, I've tried packages like `grffile` or `currfile`, but none of them work. Can anyone suggest a real solution so that I don't need to change hundreds of file names? Thanks.

Update:
1. I'm using Windows.
2. When I compile it, it shows "Illegal parameter number in definition"

Comment: Rename those files!
Get a tool like multifilerename (from sourceforge) an rename all those files in one simple step.

Comment: On Windows, if your files are named, for example, `test#1.txt`, `test#2.txt`, etc., then the command-line approach of `rename test#*.txt testZ*.txt` will work for a global rename.

Answer (score 16):

You can change the catcode of `#` before using it:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
{\catcode`\#=12 \includegraphics{test#abc}}
\end{document}
```

But it is really better to avoid such names.

Answer (score 14):

An alternative to catcode changes, which can be tricky inside macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{a\string##b.png}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought to use two hashes ;-). But it doesn't work in similar cases (e.g. \input).

Comment: The number of hash signs (one, two, four, ...) depend on the implementation. For example, this will break `grffile`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek there's the one true implementation and pale imitations:-) what you say is true though of course, although the _method_ works n general: just try doubling until the problem goes away although it's not guaranteed to work as Ulrike comments for `\input` different internal commands need different number of `#` (I wasn't expecting `#` in the filename parse...)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It could also be possible that one part of an implementation requires doubling, another part quadrupling.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You mean, there is one poor implementation that needs to be enriched by many other packages to get image support work in practice? ;-)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek yes (That's why `\input` doesn't work) I originally was going to answer with `\edef..\string` as you did in the end, but I thought I'd live on the edge. Probably that's what people should do though I suppose I should give you a vote... (done:-)

Comment: Is the square bracket surrounding the `\includegraphics` needed? This seems to be the easiest way since I can batch replace hundreds of `#` by `\string#`, but if I need to add `{\catcode}` before every `\includegraphics` it will be a big pain.

Comment: @test no sorry I deleted them (they were just random text before and after the image inclusion while I was testing what worked)

Comment: @test probably you should do as Heiko suggests

Comment: This doesn't work in latex-dev, file not found. (`\includegraphics{F#m.pdf}` gives an error but the file is found).

Answer (score 12):

Either the category code can be changed, see the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202714/16967) of Ulrike Fischer.
Or the hash can be hidden inside a macro:

```
\edef\hash{\string#}
```

`\hash` is defined as macro that expands to a hash with a category code (12/other)
of a character like digits.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{grffile}

\newcommand*{\hash}{}% print error message if \hash is already defined
\edef\hash{\string#}

\begin{document}
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{test\hash abc}% "test#abc"
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the filename-processing/parsing of the graphics/graphicx-package:

The filename provided as argument to `\includegraphics` is passed into the definition texts of temporary macros.

When these temporary macros get expanded, the amounts of consecutive hashes will be halved and single hashes will be taken for markers which should precede digits in the range 1..9 for denoting arguments.

This could probably have been resolved via `\toks@{..}...\edef..{..\the\toks@..}` or `\edef...{\unexpanded{..}..}`.

In case the `\detokenize`-primitive of the eTeX-extensions is available, checking whether a token is an explicit character token of category code 6 (parameter) can be implemented.

Thus in case the `\detokenize`-primitive of the eTeX-extensions is available, a routine for recursively replacing every hash (every explicit character token of category code 6) in the filename by its stringification/by its category-code-12-pendant can be implemented:

```
% This example uses \detokenize and thus requires eTeX extensions.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo,
%%    \UD@PassFirstToSecond, \UD@Exchange, \UD@removespace
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherNull, \UD@CheckWhetherBrace,
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace, \UD@ExtractFirstArg
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\UD@removespace{}\UD@firstoftwo{\def\UD@removespace}{} {}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's first token is a catcode-1-character
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has leading
%%                        catcode-1-token>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has no leading
%%                        catcode-1-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBrace[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{%
  \string#1.}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@firstoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether brace-balanced argument starts with a space-token
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                             {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                               which is to be checked>'s 1st token is a
%%                               space-token>}%
%%                             {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                               which is to be checked>'s 1st token is not
%%                               a space-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpaceB.#1 }{}}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpaceB{}%
\long\def\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpaceB#1 {%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@secondoftwo#1{}}%
  {\UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
  {\UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter}\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Extract first inner undelimited argument:
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{ABCDE} yields  {A}
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{{AB}CDE} yields  {AB}
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm{}%
\long\def\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1#2\UD@SelDOm{{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArg[1]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#1\UD@SelDOm}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  { #1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1}}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% \ReplaceEveryHash{<argument>}%
%%
%%   Each explicit catcode-6(parameter)-character-token of the <argument> 
%%   will be replaced by its stringification.
%%
%%   You obtain the result after two expansion-steps, i.e., 
%%   in expansion-contexts you get the result after "hitting" 
%%   \ReplaceEveryHash by two \expandafter.
%%   
%%   As a side-effect, the routine does replace matching pairs of explicit
%%   character tokens of catcode 1 and 2 by matching pairs of curly braces
%%   of catcode 1 and 2.
%%   I suppose this won't be a problem in most situations as usually the
%%   curly braces are the only characters of category code 1 / 2...
%%
%%   This routine needs \detokenize from the eTeX extensions.
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\ReplaceEveryHash[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\UD@ReplaceEveryHashLoop{#1}{}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ReplaceEveryHashLoop[2]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{ #2}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace{#1}{%
       \expandafter\UD@ReplaceEveryHashLoop
       \expandafter{\UD@removespace#1}{#2 }%
    }{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{#1}{%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
            \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@ReplaceEveryHashLoop
            \romannumeral0\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#1\UD@SelDOm}{}%
        }{#2}}%
        {\expandafter\UD@ReplaceEveryHashLoop
         \expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}}%
      }{%
       \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherHash
       \romannumeral0\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#1\UD@SelDOm}{#1}{#2}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherHash[3]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace\expandafter{\string#1}{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\UD@removespace\string#1}{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\UD@removespace\detokenize{#1}}{% Something whose stringification yields a single space
        \expandafter\UD@ReplaceEveryHashLoop
        \expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#2}{#3#1}%
      }{% Explicit space of catcode 6
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\UD@Exchange
        \expandafter{\string#1}{#3}}{%
          \expandafter\UD@ReplaceEveryHashLoop
          \expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#2}%
        }%
      }%
    }{% Something whose stringification has a leading space
      \expandafter\UD@ReplaceEveryHashLoop
      \expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#2}{#3#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo
    \expandafter{\expandafter}\string#1}{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo
      \expandafter{\expandafter}\detokenize{#1}}{% No Hash
        \expandafter\UD@ReplaceEveryHashLoop
        \expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#2}{#3#1}%
      }{% Hash
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\UD@Exchange
        \expandafter{\string#1}{#3}}{%
          \expandafter\UD@ReplaceEveryHashLoop
          \expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#2}%
        }%
      }%
    }{% No Hash
      \expandafter\UD@ReplaceEveryHashLoop
      \expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#2}{#3#1}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mytempa
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\ReplaceEveryHash{F#m.png}}

\includegraphics[width=5cm]{\mytempa}

\end{document}
```

---

But just replacing hashes is not the best solution. Reason: Besides hashes a filename might as well contain unbalanced curly braces and the like. Therefore a routine which does read from the .tex-input-file and tokenize macro-arguments under verbatim-category-code-régime might be handy.

I can offer a macro `\UDcollectverbarg` with the following syntax:

```
\UDcollectverbarg{⟨^^M-replacement⟩}{⟨mandatory 1⟩}{⟨mandatory 2⟩}⟨verbatimized argument⟩
```

which yields:

`⟨mandatory 1⟩{⟨mandatory 2⟩{⟨verbatim argument⟩}}`

, with each character `^^M` that denotes an end of a line being replaced by the token-sequence `⟨^^M-replacement⟩`.

The arguments `⟨mandatory 1⟩` and `⟨mandatory 2⟩` are mandatory. If they consist of several tokens, these tokens must be nested into a catcode-1/2-explicit-character-token-pair / into braces.
If reading and tokenizing is necessary, this will take place under unchanged category code régime.
The `⟨verbatim argument⟩` is also mandatory. It is to be read and tokenized under verbatim category code régime. If its first character is a brace, it will be "assumed" that the argument is nested into braces.  Otherwise it will be assumed, that the ending of that argument is delimited by that first character—like the argument of `\verb`.
Empty lines will not be ignored.

I chose this syntax as with this syntax you can collect verbatim arguments within `⟨mandatory 2⟩` by nesting calls to `\UDcollectverbarg` within `⟨mandatory 1⟩`.

E.g.,

```
\UDcollectverbarg{<^^M-replacement>}%
                 {\UDcollectverbarg{<^^M-replacement>}{\UDcollectverbarg{<^^M-replacement>}{<actionA>}}}% <- mandatory 1
                 {<actionB>}%                     <- mandatory 2
                 <verbatim argument 1><verbatim argument 2><verbatim argument 3>
```

yields:

```
\UDcollectverbarg{<^^M-replacement>}{\UDcollectverbarg{<^^M-replacement>}{<actionA>}}% <- mandatory 1
                 {<actionB>{<verbatimd argument 1>}}%        <- mandatory 2
                 <verbatim argument 2><verbatim argument 3>
```

yields:

```
\UDcollectverbarg{<^^M-replacement>}{<actionA>}% <- mandatory 1
                 {<actionB>{<verbatim argument 1>}{<verbatim argument 2>}}% <- mandatory 2
                 <verbatim argument 3>
```

yields:

```
<actionA>{<actionB>{<verbatim argument 1>}{<verbatim argument 2>}{<verbatim argument 3>}}
```

Assume `<actionA>` = `\@firstofone`:

```
\@firstofone{<actionB>{<verbatim argument 1>}{<verbatim argument 2>}{<verbatim argument 3>}}
```

yields:

```
<actionB>{<verbatim argument 1>}{<verbatim argument 2>}{<verbatim argument 3>}
```

---

```
% This example does not require eTeX extensions.

\errorcontextlines=10000

\makeatletter
%%<-------------------- Code for \UDcollectverbarg -------------------->
%% Copyright (C) 2007 - 2019 by Ulrich Diez (eu_angelion@web.de)
%%
%% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public Licence (LPPL), either
%% version 1.3 of this license or (at your option) any later
%% version. (The latest version of this license is in:
%% http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 1999/12/01 or later.)
%% The author of this work is Ulrich Diez.
%% This work has the LPPL maintenance status 'not maintained'.
%% Usage of any/every component of this work is at your own risk.
%% There is no warranty - neither for probably included
%% documentation nor for any other part/component of this work.
%% If something breaks, you usually may keep the pieces.
%
\newcommand\UD@firstofone[1]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
%%
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%......................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%......................................................................
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=12 %
\UD@firstofone{%
  \endgroup%
  \newcommand\UDEndlreplace[2]{\romannumeral0\@UDEndlreplace{#2}#1^^M\relax{}}%
  \newcommand*\@UDEndlreplace{}%
  \long\def\@UDEndlreplace#1#2^^M#3\relax#4#5{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#3}%
    { #5{#4#2}}{\@UDEndlreplace{#1}#3\relax{#4#2#1}{#5}}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UDcollectverbarg[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother % <- this and the next line switch to
  \dospecials        %    verbatim-category-code-régime.
  \catcode`\{=1      % <- give opening curly brace the usual catcode so a 
                     %    curly-brace-balanced argument can be gathered in
                     %    case of the first thing of the verbatimized-argument 
                     %    being a curly opening brace.
  \catcode`\ =10     % <- give space and horizontal tab the usual catcode so \UD@collectverbarg
  \catcode`\^^I=10   %    cannot catch a space or a horizontal tab as its 4th undelimited argument.
                     %    (Its 4th undelimited argument denotes the verbatim-
                     %     syntax-delimiter in case of not gathering a
                     %     curly-brace-nested argument.)
  \kernel@ifnextchar\bgroup
  {% seems a curly-brace-nested argument is to be caught:
    \catcode`\}=2    % <- give closing curly brace the usual catcode also.
    \UD@collectverbarg{#1}{#2}{#3}{}%
  }{% seems an argument with verbatim-syntax-delimiter is to be caught:
    \do\{% <- give opening curly brace the verbatim-catcode again.
    \UD@collectverbarg{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@collectverbarg[4]{%
  \do\ %   <- Now that \UD@collectverbarg has the delimiter or
  \do\^^I%    emptiness in its 4th arg, give space and horizontal tab
         %    the verbatim-catcode again.
  \do\^^M% <- Give the carriage-return-character the verbatim-catcode.
  \long\def\@tempb##1#4{%
    %\edef\@tempb{##1}%
    \def\@tempb{##1}%
    \@onelevel@sanitize\@tempb % <- Turn characters into their "12/other"-pendants.
                               %    This may be important with things like the 
                               %    inputenc-package which may make characters 
                               %    active/which give them catcode 13(active).
    \expandafter\UDEndlreplace\expandafter{\@tempb}{#1}{\def\@tempb}% <- this starts 
                               %    the loop for replacing endline-characters.
    \expandafter\UD@@collectverbarg\expandafter{\@tempb}{#2}{#3}% <- this "spits 
                               %    out the result.
  }%
  \@tempb
}%
\newcommand\UD@@collectverbarg[3]{%
  \endgroup
  #2{#3{#1}}%
}%
%%<---------------- End of code for \UDcollectverbarg ----------------->
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begingroup\catcode`\^^M=12\relax%
\UDcollectverbarg{^^M}{\endgroup\csname @firstofone\endcsname}{\def\mytempa}|F#m.png|%

\includegraphics[width=5cm]{\mytempa}

\end{document}
```

Comment: _"This could probably have been resolved ..."_ - are you describing here a bug in the `graphicsx` package?

Comment: @Eric Not necessarily a bug. Something that might probably be considered a shortcoming in the way in which arguments holding filenames are processed with `\includegraphics`. I don't know if this is documented within grfguide.pdf or wherever. If so, then in any case it is not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expl3`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\safeincludegraphics}{O{}m}
 {
  \egreg_includegraphics:ne { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_includegraphics:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__egreg_includegraphics_tl { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \cP\# } { \cO\# } \l__egreg_includegraphics_tl
  \includegraphics[#1]{\l__egreg_includegraphics_tl}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \egreg_includegraphics:nn { ne }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\test}{x##y}

\begin{document}

\safeincludegraphics[width=3cm]{x#y}

\safeincludegraphics[width=3cm]{\test}

\end{document}
```

If you want to bury the name in a macro, you still need to double the `#` tokens, as shown in the example.

### Output

[image]

### Extract from the log file

```
<x#y.pdf, id=1, 321.2pt x 240.9pt>
File: x#y.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use x#y.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: x#y.pdf  used on input line 28.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 85.35826pt x 64.0183pt.
File: x#y.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use x#y.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: x#y.pdf  used on input line 30.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 85.35826pt x 64.0183pt.
```

The file `x#y.pdf` is just a copy of the standard `example-image.pdf`.