# How to read a picture with name # in it?

Tags: macros, strings

Probably avoiding to use #  would be best at the first place but for musical chords I would like to name my image something like F#m.png . The problem is that latex does not allow to write

```
\includegraphics{F#m.png}
```

If I do

```
\includegraphics{F\#m.png}
```

Then I will get a file not found error since now F\#m is considered as the filename.

Comment: `\string#` probably works

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In [this answer of yours](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202717/82917) you write `\string##`. In fact, `\string#` works when the package `grffile` is loaded, otherwise two `##` are necessary. Interesting.

Comment: @David Carliste, thanks it works with the `grffile` loaded. For me the `\string##` did not work.

Comment: I just submitted another answer to the discussion [\includegraphics: number sign # in filename](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502413/118714). That discussion might be of interest to you. ;-)

Comment: It would probably be easier to rename the file, or add a link (shortcut) without the #.